# Fancontrol: Set fans in function of max temperature

Tags: fan, temperature, fancontrol

I would like help to know hot to configure fancontrol, I already check:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/fan_speed_control

https://man.archlinux.org/man/fancontrol.8

For now, I only found how to set one fan to one temp sensor.

File with `pwmconfig`

```
# Configuration file generated by pwmconfig, changes will be lost
INTERVAL=2
DEVPATH=hwmon0=devices/platform/coretemp.0 hwmon1=devices/platform/coretemp.1 hwmon2=
DEVNAME=hwmon0=coretemp hwmon1=coretemp hwmon2=dell_smm
FCTEMPS=hwmon2/pwm3=hwmon0/temp1_input hwmon2/pwm2=hwmon1/temp1_input hwmon2/pwm1=hwmon0/temp1_input
FCFANS=hwmon2/pwm3=hwmon2/fan3_input hwmon2/pwm2=hwmon2/fan2_input hwmon2/pwm1=hwmon2/fan1_input
MINTEMP=hwmon2/pwm3=40 hwmon2/pwm2=40 hwmon2/pwm1=40
MAXTEMP=hwmon2/pwm3=60 hwmon2/pwm2=60 hwmon2/pwm1=60
MINSTART=hwmon2/pwm3=150 hwmon2/pwm2=150 hwmon2/pwm1=150
MINSTOP=hwmon2/pwm3=0 hwmon2/pwm2=0 hwmon2/pwm1=0
```

I have 3 fans, but I want them to run based in the max temperature of all the sensors.

There is some reasons for it, I can't change the hardware, and there is two CPU fans in series, and the pc have two cpus, so to I need to both of fans running.

I have searched a lot, but can't found how to do this works, I read example/descriptions of how the config file works but there was only basic things, but not enough to learn to can do something by myself.

Ideally if someone know a good doc for this...

Thx!